# After doing latest windows10 update 1909 SQL Server Management Studio 17 not working

Tags: ssms, windows-10

yesterday I have an update for windows version 1909, after updating to the latest version, When I tried to open SSMS it shows me an error like this(please check the screenshot).[image]

Comment: Did you try following the instructions and re-installing SSMS?  Could possibly just do a "repair" install.

Comment: @JonathanFite yes I tried many times .

Comment: Now what I am going to do is uninstall visual studio and ssms, then reinstall VS then install ssms.Let me try with this

Comment: two options, 1) Install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685v), 2) Upgade to a newer version from [SQL Server Management Studio 18.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Luuk I installed SSMS 18.4 and it works fine

Comment: For anyone who also has this problem i will add this to an answer.

Comment: @Luuk ok that will be useful any one facing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Install "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable"

From some reason the link that worked yesterday now does not work (thank you Microsoft!). The working link is [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

2. Upgade to a newer version from [SQL Server Management Studio 18.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

*SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is an integrated environment for managing any SQL infrastructure, from SQL Server to Azure SQL Database. SSMS provides tools to configure, monitor, and administer instances of SQL Server and databases. Use SSMS to deploy, monitor, and upgrade the data-tier components used by your applications, and build queries and scripts.
Use SSMS to query, design, and manage your databases and data warehouses, wherever they are - on your local computer, or in the cloud.
SSMS is free!*

My, personal opinion, choose option2. SSMS 18.4 is available since 4 November 2019 and has (AFAIK) the same functionality compared to SSMS 17.x